# Encode string with UTF-8 format in go

Tags: go, utf-8

How to convert string text to utf8 in golang (go language)?

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/strings

Answer (score 0):

The string literals in go are encoded in UTF-8 by default.
From the [official golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

> Go source code is UTF-8, so the source code for the string literal is
>   UTF-8 text

However this doesn't apply to the escape characters, such as `\n`:

> If that string literal contains no escape sequences, which a raw string cannot, the constructed string will hold exactly the source text between the quotes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i'm sorry ,i meant it in wrongly ,actually i want to encode json data in UTF-8 format

Comment: Then better post another question

Comment: @shagul use the [Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal/) function, store the content in a struct, and all the strings will be encoded to utf8, except the invalid characters will be replaced by `U+FFFD`, and change all other datatypes to `String` with the [strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) package.